# Automatic insertion of ID in execution

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, frontend, backend

I have created inserting Employee details in Visual studio 2010.When I click on Add,it displays as added and the id automatically increments in backend.But instead of added,if I had to display as ("You EMP ID is somenumber(eg.10) )in front end while execution,what should I do?

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using HRMSController;
using HRMSBusinessEntities;
using System.Data;


namespace HumanResourceManagementSystems
{
    public partial class HRMSEmployee : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string username = (string)(Session["LoginUser"]);
            if (Session["LoginUser"] != null)
            {
                lblDisplay.Text = "Welcome..." + username;
            }
            Calendar1.Visible = false;
            Label1.Visible = false;
            txtcurrdate.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();
        }

        protected void Btnmodified_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Calendar1.Visible = true;
            
        }
        protected void Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            EmployeeEntity record = new EmployeeEntity
            {
                name = txtname.Text,
                currentdate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtcurrdate.Text),
                modifieddate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtmodifieddate.Text)
            };
            EmployeeController add = new EmployeeController();
            add.Add(record);
            Label1.Visible = true;
            Label1.Text = "Added" ;
            Clear();


        }
        public void Clear()
        {
            txtname.Text = "";
            txtcurrdate.Text = "";
            txtmodifieddate.Text = "";
        }

        protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtmodifieddate.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString();
        }

        protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Clear();
        }

        protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            Calendar1.Visible = true;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: could you please include the snippets?

Comment: Show your codes and explain at which line the exception happens

Comment: It's not an exception.Instead of added,it should show in the front end as Your Emp ID is (the number here ) for eg.10) @AlexJolig

Comment: @AlexJolig Please respond to propose a solution.I have the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding the record you can pull up the max id record and show the record in the UI

Query might look like

```
Select * from Employee ORDER BY EmpId DESC LIMIT 1;
```

As suggested for performance issue we can do

```
Select max(EmpId) from Employee;
```

**EDIT**

```
add.Add(record);

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnString);
con.Open();
IDbCommand Cmd = con.CreateCommand();
Cmd.CommandText = "Select max(EmpId) from Employee";
IDataReader LastID = Cmd.ExecuteReader();
LastID.Read();
Label1.Visible = true;
Label1.Text = Your Empl ID is " + LastID[0].ToString() ;
Clear();
con.Close();
```

**Another way could be**

```
protected void Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    EmployeeEntity record = new EmployeeEntity
    {
        name = txtname.Text,
        currentdate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtcurrdate.Text),
        modifieddate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtmodifieddate.Text)
    };
    EmployeeController add = new EmployeeController();
    add.Add(record);
    Label1.Visible = true;
    Label1.Text = "Your Empl ID is " + FetchLastID();
    Clear();
}

public string FetchLastID()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnString);
    con.Open();
    IDbCommand Cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    Cmd.CommandText = "Select max(EmpId) from Employee";
    IDataReader LastID = Cmd.ExecuteReader();
    LastID.Read();
    return LastID[0].ToString() ;
}
```

Comment: If the table is huge then your query will have serious performance issues.

Comment: I want it to get displayed in the front end.Instead of Added,it should display as "Your Empl ID is 10".How should I do that?

Comment: @raghav:- You need to edit your question and add some more details to it. The above solution given by Mohit is good enough to proceed with. You just need to execute this query from your C# code.

Comment: @MohitShrivastava The Label should display this message.Is it possible with your code?

Comment: @MohitShrivastava See my edited code.Instead of Added it should display as Your Emp Id is 10 or some number

Comment: @MohitShrivastava Thanks.Instead of LastID should I give EmpID?

Comment: @MohitShrivastava where should I include the fetch method?

Comment: @MohitShrivastava SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnString) The Parameter ConnString is not working.So I erased that.Will that work

Comment: Please be online for sometime,so that I can share my doubts. @MohitShrivastava

Comment: You can ask a different question for the problem you are facing with the code. I am going offline in 3 mins.

Comment: In source code,what I have to give in the text field of the label.Because currently I am getting NullReferenceException @MohitShrivastava